# Eliminating extraneous network traffic

Tags: networking, wireshark

If I wanted to get the best performance (high data rate, low latency) out of an isolated gigabit ethernet LAN (N.B. NOT connected to the internet) I would assume this would occur when there was no other network traffic apart from traffic generated by my own application. Can this theoretical goal be achieved in practice?

That is... each time I use Wireshark to look at traffic on what I think is an isolated network, I'm usually surprised to see a few stray packets here and there from unexpected sources. How easy is it to find the sources of all this extraneous network data, and turn them all off? Can the network and the systems attached to them function without all of them?

Comment: "*How easy is it to find the sources of all this extraneous network data, and turn them all off?"* -- You probably cannot inhibit *broadcast* packets (i.e. packets addressed to "every host").

Comment: I know that most hosts broadcast packets to try to discover what is connected on the network, but what if my network is static and I already know what is (or may be) connected - can I turn off such network discovery services? Is there any other specific context that employs broadcasting (or anything else) that cannot be turned off because it is essential to network or OS functioning?